# Passing a value from the parent model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2.3, Mongoid and Devise

I have two models and I need to pass the **button_color** value from the parent model

**user.rb**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :button_color, type: String, default: '#FFFFFF'

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :button_color, type: String
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

I need to get something like

**field :button_color, type: String, default: current_user.button_color**

Comment: If the `button_color ` depends on the Devise `current_user` then that value is always going to be dynamic, you need to somehow create the item with the value of current_user. If on the contrary, the default value for `button_color` is the item user, then you can use an ActiveRecord callback to set that value if not given.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class Item
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :button_color, to: :user
end
```

You can then call `button_color` on any Item instance.

```rb
puts item.button_color
```

See [delegate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) docs.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I assume `current_user` in your question is being set correctly to the `Item` object as `item.user`.

**Approach 1**

Try setting `default` option to a lambda for that field:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :button_color, type: String, default: -> { user&.button_color }

  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

**Approach 2**

If above doesn't work, you can add a [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) to set the `button_color` if it was not set to any other value:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :button_color, type: String # default `nil`

  belongs_to :user, touch: true

  before_validation :set_button_color

  private

  def set_button_color
    self.button_color ||= user&.button_color
  end
end
```